# Find twice continuously differentiable bounded function vanishing at infinity satisfying f(0)=0 and f'(0)=0?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, functions

I am looking for a twice continuously differentiable and bounded function (i.e $f$, $f'$, and $f''$ bounded) vanishing at infinity $f$ on $\mathbb{R}_+$ satisfying $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$ . Without the vanishing at infinity condition, it is easy to find such examples using trigonometric functions, but somehow with that condition things seem more complicated. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $f(x) = x^2 e^{-x}$

Comment: can we bound this?

Comment: If you want a rational function, $\left(\frac{x}{1+x^2}\right)^2$.

Comment: I think you want boundness on $\mathbb R_+$. Ok, $f(x) = x^2 e^{-x^2}$

Comment: I think it's not interesting to seek analytic functions. Maybe we can find functions such that $f\in C^2(\mathbb R)$, but $f\notin C^3(\mathbb R)$? Just for fun, of course

Comment: sorry maybe my post is not clear, but the first and second derivatives also need to be bounded, is this possible?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza man I am not on this level yet!

Comment: @user223935, add boundness of $f'$ and $f''$ to your post. For my function all derivatives are bound (exponent grows faster than any power)

Comment: @MichaelGaluza, I find $f'(x)=2xe^{-x^2}-2x^3e^{-x^2}$ for the first derivative. Is there an explicit bound on this?

Comment: @user223935, yes. You should solve $f''(x)=0$ for maximum of $f'(x)$, or $2x^4-5x^2+1$. Numerically, $f'(x)$ less or equal $0.5872090308$

Comment: @MichaelGaluza thanks man

Comment: There is a [standard construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) of $C^\infty$ functions that have all derivatives rapidly decreasing at infinity (faster than any polynomial).

Comment: $f(x)=0$. Just kidding, I don't think the trivial function is of any interest to you.
By the way, it is possible to patch a non trivial function to $f(x)=0$ in a $C^\infty$ way. For instance, $g(x) = e^{-1/x^2}$ is $C^\infty$, but $f^{(n)}(0)=0\ \forall n$. Doing the trick to patch $g(x)$ to some decaying function, you can actually build a function that satisfy $f^{(n)}(0)=0\ \forall n$, $f(x)\to 0$ for $x\to\infty$, $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and $f(x)\neq 0$ somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

What about $f(x) \equiv 0$? $$$$

Comment: It's dirty trick ;)

Comment: forgot to mention different from the null function!